# Method to making number from strings

Tags: c#

I have some words like it `flexform_mood_icaro_bed_2`. I want to write a method to generate a unique code from the above string. like a serial number or a product number.

I use `GetHashCode()` for my purpose. But the important point is that the code number should never change with the same string.
I viewed somewhere that GetHashCode will be changed by changing .net version.

Inputs contain int and string as I mentioned in the first line. I actually want to make product numbers from the product name.

So is there any method to make code numbers from strings?

Comment: Use a hashing algorithm that doesn't ever change, such as MD5 or SHA.

Comment: What about MD5/SHA(,2,3)?

Comment: How about converting each character to ascii number?

Comment: `GetHashCode()` is also not unique. And I can't imagine how to project strings to _unique_ numbers that fit into a cpu. Strings can have from 0 to a _a lot of_ characters. Let's assume you only have lower case characters and digits, that makes at least 36 possible characters. With a string of length 20, you have  36 ^ 20 possibilites, that's a _lot lot lot_ more than 2^64 (like an unsigned long). What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds like an xy-problem.

Comment: You could just use any hash algorithm (like `MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA512` etc`)....

Comment: Doesn't he want to get the number instead of string? MD5 produces string, doesn't it?

Comment: the only unique string for a given string is the same given string. any hashing algorithm has a chance of collisions.

Comment: Why don't you just use that string? (it already looks like a serial number)

Comment: MD5 produces a string that can be interpreted as a very large hex (16 base) number

Comment: Hashing functions do not necessarily result in non-collisions. `P(collision) = c/2^N` where `c` is the length of your string and `N` is the number of bits in your collision algorithm.

Comment: @CodeCaster inputs contain int and string. I actually want to make product numbers from the product name.

Comment: @DanielA.White So I can not get the same output with the same input by GetHashCode?

Comment: "Inputs contain int and string" is definitely not clear enough to answer this.

Comment: @D.JCode not im not saying that. i'm saying that for a given input named-`x` and output `f(x)`, there is a chance that named-`y` will have `f(x) == f(y)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Dude! I have some product name like: "Max Tool Kit 2", "flexform_mood_icaro_bed" and etc.  So I want to make a serial number for them.  is it clear?!

Answer (score 0):

> I have some product name like: "Max Tool Kit 2", "flexform_mood_icaro_bed" and etc. So I want to make a serial number for them. is it clear?! - [D.JCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722819/method-to-making-number-from-strings?noredirect=1#comment92371819_52722819)

No, that is not clear. Those strings also don't look anything like what you used in your question.

What you don't seem to understand, is that in order to do that, you have to choose a very specific algorithm that can mangle those particular strings (and who knows what other strings, you still haven't shown what all possible inputs are) into a unique number, in such a way that the outputs will never collide. I don't know of an algorithm that can do that.

Of course a hashing algorithm like SHA can come close to looking like that, but then you have a very, very large number as output, and still no guarantee it'll be unique for all the strings you want to handle.

What you instead should be doing, is decide what you want your serial numbers to look like, and *generate* them.

So start at a nice number, for example 1,000,000,000, then iterate over your product collection, assign the current number, and increment it by one. Repeat for all products, done.

Comment: I think I could not explain my problem clearly!
I want to write a program which it gets product name, like "Max Tool Kit 2", "flexform_mood_icaro_bed". After that program should generate a product number for each of product names. Some product had SN before, so I don't want to use the nice number system(1,000,000,000) that you mentioned. 
by the way, I want a unique number, because if in future someone gives a product name which is there, so the program generates the same number from the same input product name.

Comment: I know there are many ways to recognizing the old products. But I just know about generate a serial number from a string.

Comment: You said: *if in future someone gives a product name which is there, so the program generates the same number from the same input product name*, and I say:  `DECLARE @ser INT = (SELECT serialnumber FROM product WHERE name = @name); IF @ser IS NULL THEN @ser = generatenewserialnumber(@name) ENDIF; RETURN @ser`

Comment: @D.JCode the point is, again, that you could use a hashing algorithm, but that that cannot guarantee unicity, and it'll give extremely large numbers to work with. The smaller the resulting number, the greater the chance of collisions (two input strings resulting in the same output number).